# CSS background 100% and empty spaces in this

Tags: css, background

I have problem with creating a webpage menu - I must do something like in this picture below. This black parts is just a background around content in the middle. I want to make this left black part is extended to the left side of screen and right black part extended to right side of screen, but I can't use width:100% on the outer div because I want to leave a empty spaces between every red square.

[image]

…and on the wider screen this must be like this:

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't know how to go about it. This is my draft of code: http://pastebin.com/pMD1hQRC

Comment: @user3180931 what % width you have given to black box?

Comment: I think I can't give width:xx% to black boxes because this depends on the screen width, there is only one fixed width - 980px and this is a red boxes with margins.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJzGu)

**HTML**

```
<header>

  <div class="inner"></div>

</header>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow:hidden; /* prevent scrollbar */
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  height:100px;
  width:980px;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px solid black;


}
header:before, header:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  width:50%;
} 

header:before {
  left:0;
  margin-left:-490px; 
}

header:after {
  right:0;
  margin-right:-490px;
}
```

Comment: This is something like this! I only edited margin-right:-490px; to -500px and margin-left:-490px; to -500px to make a blank spaces, but there is another problem - horizontal scrolling bar

Comment: Add `overflow:hidden` to the `body` tag. Codepen updated

Comment: Thank you very much, this is it! :) But there's another problem, everything fine, but on the smaller screen, for example 800x600px (who use this ;d ) there is no ability to scroll page horizontally. I checked this on the android smartphone and user can scroll page horizontally, but on computer on the smaller screen there is no ability. There is a example of full page: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cKyad

Comment: At less than 960px (your fixed width) you should be using media queries so that the width changes accordingly. It's all part of having a responsive design...which, I am afraid, your design is not..as yet

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

I have updated the code as per your comment, there was a slight error, and I have removed it. check out this new link

http://jsfiddle.net/24eDx/1/

As far as I understand your question, you want to create menu bar which will be aligned center, and which looks like the one you https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm62c.jpg

I have created one `JSFiddle` for you
http://jsfiddle.net/24eDx/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-wraper">
        <div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><div class="menu-li">Menu 1</div> </li>
                <li><div class="menu-li">Menu 2</div> </li>
                <li><div class="menu-li">Menu 3</div> </li>
                <li><div class="menu-li">Menu 4</div> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header{
    background : black;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
}
.header-wraper
{
    width : 80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.header .header-wraper .menu li
{
    list-style: none;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    padding: 16px 14px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-width: 0 1px;
}
.header .header-wraper .menu li:first-child
{
    border-width: 0 1px 0 2px;
}
.header .header-wraper .menu li:last-child
{
    border-width: 0 2px 0 1px;
}
```

**P.S.** : Please, Next time do add a code you working on, that will be helpful for everyone and Also read the documentation that will help you understand how to ask a question on stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, you understand me, but on your code when I resize window the left black box width stay fixed and only right expands: http://i.imgur.com/iZQ7RgJ.jpg I wanna make the left black box equal to right black box on every resolution.

Comment: In your updated code red boxes expands on the wider screen, it was supposed to be inversely, but thank you very much for your help - Paulie_D created a code, which I need :)